# Azure point-to-site persistent connection

Tags: vpn, azure

I have a situation where I don't have access to the firewall at one of our locations, so I have installed Azure point-to-site VPN client apps on the servers there.

The problem (as I quickly found out) is that the connection can drop. And unfortunately, although it's set to redial 99 times, it doesn't actually do that.

Anyone dealt with this and know how I can make sure the VPN client connections stay up 24/7?

Comment: You might check these two articles  [**Article 1**](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2013/11/27/deconstructing-the-azure-point-to-site-vpn-for-command-line-usage) and [**Article 2**](https://tombwu.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/build-cross-subscription-windows-lab-by-using-azure-point-to-site-vpn/)... Se here as well .... [**FYI**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/5282432-auto-connect-for-point-to-site-vpn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written about it a few days ago. Basically, you need to install the Azure VPN  Client and launch it through powershell scripting. This script can be executed automatically by Windows Task Scheduler.

Here's my [post](http://www.azurekb.com/azure-always-on-vpn-point-to-site-workaround/) about it, but although I made modifications, It's based on the two links @LMFAO_A_JOKE sent you before.

Comment: Thank you! I'm more of a developer than ops, so please excuse me if this is really stupid, but your help has moved me forward to the next issue. That is routing from the Azure machines to my client, since the IP changes each reconnect. Posted the question separately at http://serverfault.com/questions/749635/azure-point-to-site-vpn-assign-static-ip