# Azure point-to-site VPN assign static IP

Tags: networking, azure, internal-dns

I'm connecting a single server at Site 1 with my Azure virtual network (10.1.0.0/24) via a Point-To-Site VPN connection (192.168.11.0/24).

The problem is that each time the connection drops and is re-dialed, the client's IP changes. I need to connect to the single server from a server on my Azure network.

I do have a DC running DNS on my Azure network. Is there a way to configure my DNS server to allow my Machine1 at 10.1.0.5 to connect to Machine2 and it route properly to 192.168.11.4?

Comment: crap workaround: if you only have 1 ip to keep track of, try adding several entries to the hosts file pointing to the same server. Something like: 192.168.0.1 srv01, 192.168.0.2 srv02 ... and so on for at least the first 10 possible ips of the vpn range. Worked for a use case of mine. Takes a few seconds to 1-2 minutes to refresh internal dns once the vpn reconnects.

Comment: can't edit comment, i meant 192.168.0.1 srv01, 192.168.0.2 srv01, always pointing to the same server no matter the ip.

Comment: Appreciate the thought. I tried to simplify for example sake, but I actually have a handful of servers on both sides, individually connected by client VPN, so that won't work :-(