# Consistent way to access a computer on an Azure Point-To-Site VPN

Tags: vpn, azure

Our organization has a laptop that we want to be able to access from anywhere in the world. (Specifically, we need to run queries from the SQL Server running on that laptop.)

I have set up an Azure Point-to-Site VPN. I can then use the VPN to run our SQL queries, *when I know the IP address of the laptop*. I expect, however, that at some point there will be a connection loss and the laptop will get a different IP address from the VPN.

To anticipate one response, we do *not* have a static public IP address, which I believe precludes setting up a DNS server.

This could be solved if I could get a static IP address from the VPN (as in [this unanswered question](https://serverfault.com/questions/749635/azure-point-to-site-vpn-assign-static-ip)), though I am open to other solutions. For instance, if it were possible to access the computer through the Windows computer name, that would be great.

I apologize for any imprecision or unclarity in this question; I'm filling in at work for the guy who would normally do this stuff. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dynamic dns service. Have your border device update the DDNS service when it detects that the external IP address has changed. If your border device can't do the detect/update, have the laptop do it. Also ensure that the laptop has a permanent IP address on your lan.

Comment: Just to clarify... I create a domain name that points to the computer's IP address on the VPN (and update it appropriately). Then if another computer tries to access that domain name, it will get the IP address from the DDNS, and (if it is connected to the VPN) it will automatically access that address through the VPN. Is that it?

Comment: Pretty much yes.